# SVN - SQLite - disk I/O error

Tags: sqlite, svn

When trying to commit to my SVN repository, I got the following error:

```
Working copy 'Z:\prace-pj\projects\other\CopyRT' locked.
```

So I run the `clean up` command and then the commit succeeded, but at the end of the response message, there was the following error:

```
Error bumping revisions post-commit (details follow): 
disk I/O error, executing statement 'RELEASE   s11'
```

Now when I try to e.g. update the repository, it says that it is stil locked. When I clean up and try to update again, I get an error like this:

```
disk I/O error, executing statement 'RELEASE   s2'
sqlite: disk I/O error
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Cygwin?

Comment: No - I have Solaris running at the server side and at the client I use MS Windows + Tortoise SVN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried:

```
svn unlock --force path/to/workingcopy
```

? Seems it can be pointed at a url if the problem is in the repository itself... I've only used an unlock operation via the tortoise gui before, but I assume it just wraps the svn command anyway.

hope that helps

Comment: I'm using Tortoise SVN too, so I tried `Get lock` on all files and then `Release lock` on all files and now it seems to work fine (I tried both an update and a commit). Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For others reference, I just had this same error and found that one of my log files was taking up all my space (and could not write to the HDD because there was no free space).

Run (to make sure you have enough disk space)

```
df -h
```

Then I just needed to run:

```
svn cleanup
```

This resolved the error for me.

Comment: just `svn cleanup` did the job.